# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file, when using sftp put to transfer file to remote host in python

Tags: python, paramiko

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=HostIP, username=Username, password=Password)

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put('C:\mytestfile.xml', '/var/lib/Controls/mytestfile.xml')
```

When I try to transfer a file, I get the following error,
`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file`, but the file exists

Comment: Well, does the file exist? Check for spelling mistakes

Comment: It exists for sure

Comment: Are you on Windows, Linux, or Mac?

Comment: I am trying to transfer a file from Windows to linux

Answer (score 0):

You should use Unix style path when using windows path:

```
r'C:/mytestfile.xml'
```

It happens that some modules cannot read well windows path.